# Problem with numeric_limits

Tags: c++, numeric

Why this doesn't work?

```
enum : long {MaxValue = std::numeric_limits<long int>::max()};
```

I'm getting error :**Error 1 error C2057: expected constant expression**
What isn't constant about it? Limits of long int are known at compile time so what's the problem?

Comment: `static constexpr T max(); // (since C++11)` ... but this doesn't work as a compile-time constant in Visual Studio 2012 (still gives C2057), even though VS 2012 supports a lot of C++11 features.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that although `std::numeric_limits<long int>::max()` function returns constant value it is **called in run-time** and you need constant value in compile-time

Probably you can just use `LONG_MAX` value instead (see [climits](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/climits/) header)?

Comment: thank you for your answer +1. Is there any (legal) way to bypass this illogical behaviour?

Comment: C++0X introduces `constexpr` which will help address this kind of issues

Comment: Boost also has the `boost::integer_traits` class template with `const_min` and `const_max` members.

Comment: std::numeric_limits<long int>::max() *can* be evaluated to a constant expression at compile time.

Comment: @JP19 : Any idea Why this does not work in windows VC++ 2008 but works in gcc?

Answer (score 3):

As the other have said, you need a constant expression (functions don't qualify). Eventually C++1x will support a wider range of constant expressions, including functions. See [n2235](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2235.pdf) and Bjarne Stroustrup's [FAQ entry](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#constexpr).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but a function cannot be executed at compile time. `max()`

Comment: See. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compile_time_function_execution. Maybe GCC does not support CTFE, BUT - in this context, max() is most likely inlined, and returns a constant, hence it can be evaluated fine by GCC at compile time.